# negate one textbox from $('input[type="text"]')

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have 4 textboxes, I wrote some code:

```
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
...
```

I do not want to apply this code to 1 texbox, what should I do ?

Answer (score 3):

Give that textbox an `id` and update your code like this:

```
$('input[type="text"]:not("#id_of_txt")').keyup(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
    }
});
```

This solution is just to answer your question, and not to suggest as a good practice. You might at some point add further input boxes in the DOM, and you will have to keep adding to the `:not` list as everything else will be bound to the keyup event.

The better solution is to give the three input boxes a common class, and update your code like this:

```
$('input.class_of_txt').keyup(function () {
```

Comment: Very poor solution for the future... the list of ids can become quite long :).

Comment: As poor as it is, it answers the OP's question to the T. I can now update the answer and post better solutions and advice on how to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

Add a common class to the 3 textboxes.

```
<input type="text" class="myclass" />
```

And then only reference that class:

```
$('.myclass').keyup(function () {
```

Any other solution will reduce the maintainability of your code. What if there will be another special textbox? You will make an exception for that also?